# Separating structure and skin with ITCSS, BEM, and OOCSS

Tags: css, oocss, itcss

I am creating a stylesheet inspired by ITCSS, BEM, and OOCSS and am unsure how to separate structure properties from cosmetics properties.

An example as I understand ITCSS and OOCSS:

```
//First the structure. Button is an object (ITCSS)
.o-btn {
    height: ...;
    width: ...;
}

//Then declare the cosmetics in components
.c-btn-login {
    background: ...;
    color: ...;
    ...
}
```

What I have problems to see are more related with ITCSS. Two different prefixes (two categories) for the same element, when I could have the same prefix for the same element, and probably be more clear to understand.

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I think the `c-btn-login` way is wrong. In this case the component is the form.

```html
<form class="o-form c-form-login t-form-dark" >
  <input type="text" class="o-input">
  <input type="password" class="o-input" >
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="o-btn">
</form>
```

With this structure you can apply cosmetic styles with the `t-form-dark` class for all component children or use a specific class for a child like `t-btn-dark`.

```css
.t-form-dark {
    .o-input{}
    .o-btn{}
}
```

Comment: In that case, do you declare form as an object (only structure) and then as a component (cosmetics)?

Comment: i use component class c-form-login for specific styles and theme class t-form-dark for cosmetics styles... if added cosmetics styles in the c-form-login i can't use this styles in other forms... think in a website we have a c-form-login, c-form-contact, c-form-newsletter, c-form-search, c-form-user-profile, etc....then create a t-form for styles all my forms, if a want a specific style for c-form-login then create theme class called t-form-login for that

Comment: Yes, those different classes for different forms make sense. But I would use the "t-" classes for the general theme of the web, not for elements. Theses methodologies (or architectures) seems to have a personal point of view. Anyway, thanks for your comment, I see it clearer now.